# Conditions needed to approximate a Binomial distribution using a Normal distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, approximation, binomial-distribution

Okay. So, many sources state different conditions for approximating binomial using normal. Variations I've seen are as follows. Assuming that we have Bin(n,p):
1. np and n(1-p) are both large (say, 20 or bigger)
2. large n, p close to 0.5
3. large n, np>9(1-p)

My questions:
1. Are all 3 of these valid? Justify your answer.
2. Is there a set of conditions which can summarise all 3 given above (if they are valid)?

Note: Before any of you say "First, what is your opinion about this?", I personally don't know much about these distributions since I'm studying stats at a basic level. I know quite a few distributions and a bit about pdf's, cdf's, mgf's but not really that much more

Answer (score 3):

First, versions of all three of your conditions can be useful. Practically speaking, the main goal is to keep the approximating normal distribution from putting much of its probability below $0$ or above $n.$
This idea gives rise to your #3 as follows: To keep most of the normal probability above $0$, you want normal parameters $\mu$ and 
$\sigma$ to satisfy 
$$ 0 < \mu - 3\sigma = np - 3\sqrt{np(1-p)}$$
Which implies
$ np > 3\sqrt{np(1-p)}$ or $np/(1-p) > 9.$ Some authors are happy enough
with $np/(1-p) > 5.$  In the best case, you can expect only about two-place accuracy when approximating binomial probabilities by normal ones. 
Rhe stricter rule usually makes the approximation a little better. [A similar argument to ensure $n > \mu - 3\sigma$ gives the same kind
of bound: $n(1-p)/p > 9$ (or 5).]

The rule that the smaller of $np$ and $n(1-p)$ should exceed some number
is just a simplified version of the above where the denominator in the previous argument is set to 1. I have seen suggested bound as small as 5, but 20 will
usually give better results.

The rule that $p \approx 1/2$ just recognizes that the approximating normal
distribution is symmetrical, and the binomial is also symmetrical when $p=1/2.$
Saying that $n$ should be 'large' is always a safe suggestion.

---

Three further comments on normal approximation to the binomial are also relevant.

(a) It is important to use the continuity correction unless $n$ is several hundred.

(b) A Poisson approximation is often better than a normal approximation,
especially if $n$ is large and $p$ is small.

(c) Nowadays, modern software (R, SAS, Minitab, MatLab, etc.) provides the opportunity to get *exact* binomial probabilities. In practical situations
the normal approximation is usually avoided.

[But the approximation persists
in theoretical probability texts: It is a nice
illustration of the Central Limit Theorem. It makes doing 
exercises possible by using the (still ubiquitous) printed table of the normal
CDF in the 'back of the book'.]

---

**Some illustrative examples** using R statistical software.

*Breaks all the rules except $p = .5$, yet the normal approximation
happens to work quite well.*

Let $X \sim Binom(3, .5).$ Find $P(X = 2) = P(1.5 < X < 2.5).$

```
  dbinom(2, 3, .5)
  ## 0.375       # exact
  mu = 3*.5;  sg = sqrt(3*.5*.5); diff(pnorm(c(1.5, 2.5), mu, sg))
  ## 0.3758935   # norm aprx
```

*Large $n$ and small $p$. Satisfies all rules, but normal approximation is
relatively poor and Poisson approximation is better.*

Let $X \sim Binom(1000, .03)$ Find $P(X \le 2)$.

```
 pbinom(20, 1000, .03)
 ## 0.03328078      # exact via binom CDF
 sum(dbinom(0:20, 1000, .03))
 ## 0.03328078      # exact via binom PDF
 mu = 1000*.03; sg = sqrt(1000*.03 *.97);  pnorm(20.5, mu, sg)
 ## 0.03911311      # relatively poor normal aprx
 ppois(20, mu)
 ## 0.03528462      # better Poisson aprx
```

*Rules satisfied and normal approximation gives 2-place accuracy.*

Let $X \sim Binom(100, .3).$  Find $P(24 < X \le 35) = P(24.5 < X < 35.5).$

```
 diff(pbinom(c(24, 35), 100, .3))
 ## 0.7703512       # exact
 sum(dbinom(25:35, 100, .3))
 ## 0.7703512       # exact
 mu = 100*.3;  sg=sqrt(100*.3*.7);  diff(pnorm(c(24.5, 35.5), mu, sg))
 ## 0.7699377       # relatively good normal aprx
 diff(ppois(c(24, 35), mu))
 ## 0.6853745       # inappropriate Poisson 'aprx'
```

---

The figures below show blue bars for binomial probabilities, smooth curves for
normal densities, small circles for Poisson probabilities, and vertical dotted lines to bound approximating areas. Red indicates a relatively poor fit.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The usual conditions are that $n\geq 50$ and both $np$ and $n(1-p)>5$.

Note that if $p$ is close to $0.5$ your third condition is inconsistent with your first condition.

Answer (score 0):

The Berry-Esseen theorem says that the uniform CDF error for approximating a sum of $n$ iid variables with 3 moments is bounded by $\frac{C \rho}{\sigma^2 \sqrt{n}}$, where $\rho=E[|X_i-m|^3]$ and $C$ is a universal constant. We do not exactly know the best possible value of $C$ but we do know that $0.4<C<0.5$. For the binomial distribution this gives a bound of

$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{p^3(1-p)+p(1-p)^3}{p^{3/2} (1-p)^{3/2} n^{1/2}}.$$

This bound is not tight, as can be checked by some direct calculation, but it is not bad (it is more pessimistic than the true error by a factor of maybe 4 or so). Cancelling as is possible, you get a bound of

$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{p^2+q^2}{(npq)^{1/2}}$$

where $q=1-p$. The numerator there is between $1$ and $1/2$, so we can intuitively understand this bound

$$\frac{C}{(npq)^{1/2}}$$

where what I have said so far tells us only that $C$ can be chosen to be smaller than $1/2$, though in actuality for the binomial distribution it can be chosen to be a fair bit smaller than that.

So if, say, you want a uniform error of at most $0.01$ then it will be enough (by the above analysis) to have $n>\frac{10000}{16 pq}$. In actuality the cutoff is probably more like $n>\frac{100}{pq}$.