# CLT for proportions. Why does the success-failure condition have to be greater than 10 for both successes and failures?

Tags: statistics, central-limit-theorem

I am taking a course on statistics and I see this:

[image]

I don't get why there need to be 10 successes and 10 failures in the sample. What's the intuition behind why this needs to be a condition for the sampling distribution of sample proportions to be normal. Is it because if the probability of success was say 95% and `n` was 100, it's likely that sometimes, samples will produce a number of failures == 0? If that's the case, the probability of that sample will be 100%? Why wouldn't the sampling distribution be normally distributed around 95%?

Comment: You're using a normal approximation to a binomial distribution. The rule about having at least 10 successes and at least 10 failures is one of many that is alleged to ensure that that normal approximation is going to give reasonable results.

Comment: But why? Can you explain the intuition?

Comment: Roughly speaking you need for the approximating normal density not to have significant probability below 0 or above n. There must be half a dozen 'rules' intended to prevent this. A good rule is complicated. A rule that is easy to remember is not so good. Mostly, authors try for 'easy to remember'. Maybe look at [_this_](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2021801/conditions-needed-to-approximate-a-binomial-distribution-using-a-normal-distribu/2021883#2021883). Whether you find it 'intuitive' is up to you.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if the following explanation is the origin motivation for requiring that $np\geq 10$ and $n(1-p)\geq 10$.

For a normal distribution, 99.7% of data should be within 3 standard deviations away from the center.

The proportion of a random sample must be between 0 and 1. Suppose that the population proportion is neither $0$ or nor $1$.

A normal distribution with the mean $\mu=\hat{p}$ and the standard deviation $\sigma=\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}}$ is a good approximation to the distribution of sample proportions with the size $n$ if the interval (which consists of 99.7% of samples)
$$
\left[\hat{p}-3\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}}, \hat{p}+3\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}}\right]
$$
is contained in $(0, 1)$.
Then the above requirement is equivalent to that
\begin{equation} n\hat{p}>9(1-\hat{p}),\tag{1} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} n(1-\hat{p})>9\hat{p}. \tag{2}\end{equation}
Given the fact that $\hat{p}$ can be close to 0 or 1. If we assume that $n\hat{p}\geq 10$ and $n(1-\hat{p})\geq 10$. Then both inequalities (1) and (2) are satisfied.